# docker networking - host mode vs bridge mode - port mapping

Tags: docker, jenkins, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, lxc-docker

In production, `host` mode networking is recommended over `bridge` mode to avoid packet forwarding overhead.

```
$ docker container run --help | grep "network"
      --network network                Connect a container to a network
      --network-alias list             Add network-scoped alias for the container
```

---

Cloudformation resource type `AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition` option([NetworkMode](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-taskdefinition.html#cfn-ecs-taskdefinition-networkmode)) internally use decides the network mode to launch docker containers, where it says:

> If the network mode is `host`, you cannot run multiple instantiations of the same task on a single container instance when port mappings are used.

---

Using `AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition`,

Am launching single instance of master jenkins(docker container) with port mapping of `8080:8080`. EC2 port 8080 mapping with container port 8080.

---

What does it mean to say? *cannot run multiple instantiations of the same task on a single container instance when port mappings are used*....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using `network mode` as host, the container shares the host’s networking namespace as described [here](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/) and hence port mapping does not take effect. This means that you cannot map the container's port 8080 to host's port 80 because when the container exposes port 8080, it will be available directly at port 8080 in the host machine.

> cannot run multiple instantiations of the same task on a single
>   container instance when port mappings are used....

Container instance is basically a special type of EC2 instance as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_instances.html). That means if you are running more than 1 instantiations of the same task in the same host machine (container instance), they will expose the same port (e.g. 8080) which in turn maps directly to the same port on the host machine and hence leads to conflict.

Comment: Got it... So, I will run instance of master Jenkins container on EC2  and I don't need to map ports. Isn'it

Comment: Yes, that's right because you are using host network. Those port mappings will not take effect anyway!